# Why std::shared_ptr differ from std::unique_ptr w.r.t. array deleter?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I never understood why `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` differ when used with arrays, i.e. why do I have to explicitly specify the deleter for `std::shared_ptr`? I know I have to do it, I don't understand why it was designed like this.

For example, for an array of type `class Foo{...};`, using a `std::unique_ptr` is straightforward:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo[]> upFoo(new Foo[128]);
```

whereas for a `std::shared_ptr` things are uglier

```
// must specify deleter :(
std::shared_ptr<Foo> spFoo( new Foo[128], []( Foo *p ) { delete[] p; } );
```

More than that, the compiler allows me to write something like

```
// don't do it :(
std::shared_ptr<Foo> spFoo( new Foo[128]);
```

but then at deletion calls `delete spFoo;` instead of the correct `delete[] spFoo;`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, didn't find the question before on so. The answer is kind of funny though :)